# How to expand constraints to include max working hours within 48hrs?

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, genetic-algorithm

I have a script which schedules X number of workers in a 24/7 roster according to Y number of constraints. The output is each worker's 24hr schedule which is repeated every day.

Current constraints include max consecutive hours working on a machine, max cumulative number of hours working on a machine per day, max presence at work (hours on machine + breaks at work).

My question is how do I introduce a constraint which limits the cumulative number of hours working on a machine every 48hrs (or two days) and introduces a mandatory off day after every six days.

```
//these are the current parameters
param1 = {
    "nWorkers": 9, //no. of workers
    "nHours":24, //no. of hours in a day
    "maxContinuousOnMachine": 2, //consecutive onMachine
    "maxMachineHours": 6, //cumulative onMachine per day
    "maxHoursAtWork": 8 //onMachine+Breaks during Wrok
}
params.append(param1)

//below are functions that shows how the constraints are currently executed
def start_end(worker):
    start, end = -1,-1
    for i in range(len(worker)):
        if worker[i] == 1:
            start = i
            break
    for i in reversed(range(len(worker))):
        if worker[i] == 1:
            end = i
            break
    return start, end

def max_consec(worker, maxContinuousOnMachine):
    consec = 0
    for i in range(len(worker)):
        if worker[i]:
            consec +=1
        else:
            consec = 0
        if consec > maxContinuousOnMachine:
            logging.info("fail in maxContinuousOnMachine")
            return False
    return True

def max_presence(worker, maxHoursAtWork):
    start, end = start_end(worker)
    logging.info("Start: %s End: %s", str(start), str(end))
    if end - start + 1 > maxHoursAtWork:
        logging.info("fail in maxHoursAtWork")
        return False
    return True

def max_hours(worker, maxMachineHours, maxHoursAtWork):
    if sum(worker) > maxMachineHours:
        return False

    start, end = start_end(worker)

    logging.info("Start: %s End: %s", str(start), str(end))
    if end - start > math.ceil(maxMachineHours + maxHoursAtWork*0.2):
        logging.info("fail in maxMachineHours")
        return False
    return True

# check that the worker can work in the new hour and all constraints are satisfied.
def can_work(worker, hour, constraints):
    if worker[hour] == 1:
        return False
    worker[hour] = 1
    if not max_consec(worker, constraints["maxContinuousOnMachine"]) or not max_presence(worker, constraints["maxHoursAtWork"]) or \
            not max_hours(worker, constraints["maxMachineHours"], constraints["maxHoursAtWork"]) or not consec_and_rest(worker, constraints["maxContinuousOnMachine"]):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: (1) Increase the planning horizon to six days. (2) I would initially use a solver to attack this problem (and use a meta-heuristic only if the problem size warrants this).

Comment: Hmm, what is the thinking behind a planning horizon of six days if their off days shouldn't coincide seeing as the machine needs to be manned even on the 7th day? I intuitively thought I would change the nHours param to 7days*24hrs then somehow code in an off day for each person which is the part I am not sure of. Maybe it will take the same structure as the max_presence function? Hmm but what would that look like?

Comment: I think you are correct: in each 7 day period there should be one day off. So the planning period is 7 days. The day off becomes just an additional constraint.

Comment: In [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/01/employee-scheduling-i-matlab-vs-gams.html) (and subsequent posts) you can see some different approaches using mixed integer programming.